# calling delegates in viewdidload

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Quick question,

i have made a custom delegate

PupilView.h

```
@protocol DismissPupilViewPopoverDelegate
- (int) getPupilViewReason;
@end


@interface PupilView : UIViewController{
    id<DismissPupilViewPopoverDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DismissPupilViewPopoverDelegate> delegate;
```

It is called in PupilView.m like follows

```
[[self delegate] getPupilViewReason];
```

in in my maincontroller.h

```
#import "PupilView.h"

@interface MainScreen : UIViewController<DismissPupilViewPopoverDelegate>
```

maincontroller.m

```
-(int) getPupilViewReason
{
    return 100;
}
```

If i put the [[self delegate] getPupilViewReason]; in any function in pupilview.m it works perfectly, returns 100 i can see it with a breakpoint etc.

If i put it in viewdidload it dosn't load, returns 0, dosnt hit breakpoints etc. Any help as to why.

thanks

Comment: you could probably find out by trying to call it. (if your delegate is set then I don't see why it wouldn't work)

Comment: if i call it in another other function it seems to work, in viewdidload it dosn't, i was wondering if it possible to do this or if i have to do something different

Comment: You should follow the naming conventions of Objective-C: `getPupilViewReason`.

Comment: I'm guessing that the delegate is nil in viewDidLoad, can you check that?

Comment: @allprog Whilst **YES** they should be using the correct naming conventions to make life easier, you shouldn't be editing code in a question to correct this as this would in-turn change the nature of the question and would not longer be the the actual code they want us to work on. I know it was only changing the `GetPupilViewReason` to `getPupilViewReason` but you shouldn't edit it.

Comment: yes the delegate returns nothing

Comment: @Popeye I agree with you in most cases but look at Hermione333 's  answer... People should correct their own code. If they can't, then others may do it for them. I feel like my change didn't alter the context or the point of the question.

Comment: @allprog well either way you didn't correct it you just changed the first later from "G" to "g" please read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE . You don't use "get" in objective-c. So I stick to my original comment you shouldn't edit code in a question as you can change the context of the question or in your case give incorrect information.

Comment: @Popeye the OP has changed the code to the proposed version so we all can be happy. I don't use `get` in my code, I actually try to avoid using protocols too as they distort the code in most cases (blocks and ReactiveCocoa are my best friends). If this discussion has made user2336727 a tiny bit better programmer, then I'm already satisfied. Thanks for the link, I haven't read that doc for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a custom init method for the view controller where you pass the delegate so you can set the delegate in the init method before viewdidload is called.

```
@interface
- initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate nibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
//...
@end

@implementation
    - initWithDelegate:aDelegate nibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil{
      self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
          if (self) {
            _delegate = aDelegate;
            ///rest of init implementation
           }
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad{
           [super viewDidLoad];

           [self.delegate getPupilViewReason];

    }
//...
@end
```

Comment: This is good habit but does not work if the ViewController is initialized from Storyboard. If there is such delegate and Storyboard is used, then it's best to set up the delegate in the `prepareForSegue` callback. If there is no Storyboard, then your answer is the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and call. If the delegate is set up properly then it should work. Do you mean when you're doing a segue UI transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the delegate in viewDidLoad function.

Suppose your delegate(request owner) name is "delegate" then you can call like -

```
       - (void)viewDidLoad
           {
               [super viewDidLoad];

               [<OBJ>.delegate GetPupilViewReason];

           }
```

OBJ - is the instance of a class, have assign the delegate.